# WCF EntityFrameWork Exception in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I need help configuring my WCF service that access a SQL database through EF. The service runs fine when I launch it locally through visual studio, but when I deploy it to another server and access it through my client application I keep getting "{"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."}" error.

My Connection string before I publish the service to the server is:

```
<configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ECUWebUi-20121116095239;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ECUWebUi-20121116095239.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My Connection string after I publish:

```
<configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=ECUWeb-Staging;User ID=user;Password=password" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is the call to the EF context in the service:

```
public RegisterResponse Register(RegisterRequest request)
{
    EfDataAccessFactory factory = new EfDataAccessFactory(new DtoMapper());
    RegisterResponse response = new RegisterResponse();

    if (request.Computer.Exists())
    {
        factory.ComputerDataAccess.Update(request.Computer);
        response.Message = string.Format("{0} is already registered.", request.Computer.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        request.Computer = factory.ComputerDataAccess.Insert(request.Computer);
        response.Message = string.Format("{0} registered with id: {1}", request.Computer.Name, request.Computer.Id);
    }

    RegisterInstances(request);

    return response;
}
```

Any suggestions? Also the Inner Exception is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it I had to add:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ECUWeb-Staging;User Id = user; Password = password" />
    <add name="EcuWeb.Data.EcuWebDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ECUWeb-Staging; User Id = user; Password = password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then it worked no problem.